# Generating very large Random numbers using Boost library

Tags: c++, boost, random

I am using boost library for generating very very large Random numbers in the range [0-2^32-1]. But boost library is not working well with this range. It just displaying an error message "Assertion failed min_arg<=max_arg"
Kindly help me out ! here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath> 
#include "boost/random.hpp" 
#include <stdint.h>
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
long double rangeMin = 0; 
long long int  rangeMax = (pow(2.0,32.0)-1); 
typedef boost::uniform_int<> NumberDistribution; 
typedef boost::mt19937 RandomNumberGenerator; 
typedef boost::variate_generator<RandomNumberGenerator&, 
                               NumberDistribution> Generator; 

NumberDistribution distribution(rangeMin, rangeMax); 
RandomNumberGenerator generator; 
Generator numberGenerator(generator, distribution); 
generator.seed(time(0)); // seed with the current time 

cout << numberGenerator() <<endl; 
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/uniform_int.html), the default value of the template parameter of `boost::uniform_int` is `int`. If you want to generate `long long int`'s, you'll need to use `boost::uniform_int<long long int>`.

Comment: thanks its working ! What should i do if i want to store all random numbers in an array with this provided range [0-2^32-1].

Comment: You should use a vector.